# Object Reference not set to an instance of an object (Mapping a List to Automapper)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to add a list to the dto, in order for the dto top be mapped to an actual context class using AutoMapper, for some reason when i add the List to the dto's attribute and map it, upon debugging it throws an error with the exception:

```
The object reference is set to null.
```

DevDto.cs: (This is the Dto):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Auth.Models;
namespace Auth.Dtos
{
    public class DevDto
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DevController (Class where the dto is trying to map to the Developer class):

```
  public IHttpActionResult SaveDev(DevDto dev)
    {

        List<Tags> tags = new List<Tags>();

            foreach(var ss in dev)
        {
            tags.Add(_context.Tag.Single(m => m.Id == ss.TagId));
        } 
            foreach(var tt in tags)
        {
            dev.Tags.Add(tt);
        }
            var de = Mapper.Map<DevDto, Developers>(dev);
            _context.Developer.Add(de);
```

Note: The Developer and Tag class have a one to many relationship respectively as the Developer class has Tag defined as:

```
public Tags Tag{get; set;}
```

Similarly the Tag class has Developer defined as:

```
public ICollection<Developer> Developer {get; set;}
```

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Not enough information to answer the question.  What is `Developers`.

Comment: Why use a `foreach` when you can just `dev.Tags.AddRange(tags)`?

Answer (score 3):

The error is occuring because the property `Tags` of class DevDto is not instantiated when you are adding items to it, hence the error. Read more about the exception here - [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

What you can do as a `null-check` practice is to instantiate the class containing properties of `ICollection types` as follows:

```
    public class DevDto
    {
        //Null-exception check
        public DevDto()
        {
            Tags = new List<Tags>();
        }


        public byte Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If there is already an answer to this question you should vote to close as a duplicate. If there is anything new that you are adding then consider answering in the duplicate.

Comment: I have answered before it was marked duplicate. However, the answer is related to fix the exception occurred, not to show what is the exception.

Comment: But you referenced the duplicate in your answer...